# signaled in paralel query server erorr in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query like this.

```
PROCEDURE Update_Student(p_st_date)
IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO  student(student_id) 
select student_id from old_student st, old_emails em
where st.id = em.id and st.date = TO_DATE( '''||p_st_date||''',''dd.mm.yyyy'') '
END Update_Student
```

I run this query I get below error.

```
ERROR:ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P007
```

My select query return 24 k rows.Dou you have ant idea why I get this error.I tried some alter statements  like that `alter session set events '10384 trace name context forever , level 16384';`
but it is not working.

Comment: Can you post the *entire* error message? With parallel queries, the important error message is often the second one in the error stack. Unfortunately a lot of programs only display `SQLERRM` instead of the full error stack, so you might have to modify your program to not catch and mangle the error message and let Oracle display the whole thing. (Another unrelated item - the append hint must go right after the `INSERT`, not after the `INTO`.)

Comment: I wrote full error message.I fixed append section.Thank you

Comment: That is not the full error message. For parallel queries you need to post the entire error message stack. The first line will be worthless, you really need the second line. If you don't see a second line, then your program is hiding the full error messages somehow.

Comment: Do not use concatenation for values in `execute immediate`, use bind variables instead

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing dynamic in query you wrote, so - why dynamic SQL?

Start with

```
insert into student (student_id) 
select st.student_id 
from old_student st join old_emails em on st.id = em.id
--
-- after you edited the question: you should pass P_ST_DATE as DATE datatype and then
where st.date = p_st_date
-- if P_ST_DATE is VARCHAR2, then apply TO_DATE to it
```

and then - if you must - apply the hint.

Comment: I updated my question.I have to use Execute immediate :(

Comment: You have to? Why? Because of a parameter? Nope, you don't. I edited code I previously posted, have a look.